# $x \ge |a| \leftrightarrow x \ge a \land x \ge -a $?

Tags: proof-verification, absolute-value

$x \ge |a| \leftrightarrow x \ge a \land x \ge -a $ ?

> WTS $x \ge |a| \rightarrow x \ge a \land x \ge -a $ 
>       Since $|a| > -a$ then we have $x \ge -a$ 
>       Since $|a| > a$ then we have $x \ge a$  
>   Then $x \ge |a| \rightarrow x \ge a \land x \ge -a $ 
>   WTS $x \ge a \land x \ge -a\rightarrow x \ge |a| $ 
>       Case 1: $a \ge 0$ 
>           Since $a = |a|$ then we have $x \ge |a|$ 
>           Since $|a| > -a$ we still have $x \ge -a$ by $x \ge |a| > -a$ 
>       Case 2: $a < 0$ 
>           Since $-a = |a|$ then we have $x \ge |a|$ 
>           Since $|a| > a$ we still have $x \ge a$ by $x \ge |a| > a $ 
>       In both cases we have $x \ge |a|$ 
>   Then $x \ge a \land x \ge -a\rightarrow x \ge |a| $ 
>   Then $x \ge |a| \leftrightarrow x \ge a \land x \ge -a $

Is my proof correct? Are there any unnecessary components? Is there a way to do this without cases? Also is it possible to derive this equivalence from either

> $|a| \le b \leftrightarrow -b \le a \le b$

or

> $|a| \ge b \leftrightarrow a \le -b \lor b \le a$

?

Comment: What does WTS stand for?

Comment: @Alraxite "Want to show"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof seems basically correct if somewhat verbose. There are, however, two places where you say "since $|a|>a$" and two where you say "since $|a|>-a$"; all of these should be $\ge$, not $>$.

An easier way to do this, with fewer cases, is as follows: first suppose $a\ge 0$. Then $x\ge |a|$ is the same as $x\ge a$, and since $-a\le 0$, we have $-a\le a\le x$, so that $x\ge -a$ as well. If on the other hand $a\le 0$, then $x\ge |a| = |-a|$ implies (by the first part) that $x\ge -a$ and $x\ge -(-a) = a$, so again the result holds.

As you point out, you can also derive this from the fact that $|a| \le b \leftrightarrow -b \le a \le b$: $x\ge |a| \leftrightarrow -x \le a \le x$, so that $-x\le a$ and $a\le x$; multiplying the first inequality by $-1$ gives $x\ge -a$ and $x\ge a$.

Comment: Thank you! Yes maybe I am a bit verbose haha

Comment: @jmazz Also, the second lines of both the cases (lines 8 and 11) are completely unnecessary in your proof since the first sentence in each case has already demonstrated $|a|\le x$.

Comment: @Alraxite thanks. I had those because I thought I needed to state that both a and b were true from "$a \land b$" in order for the implication to be valid.

Comment: @jmazz Proving $(a\land b) \rightarrow c$ means that you have to show $c$ is true, no matter how you do it, from the assumptions $a$ and $b$. If you already know $a \rightarrow c$ then whenever someone tells you that $a\land b$ is true then, in particular, $a$ is true and so you can immediately conclude $c$ is true. It doesn't matter whether you can conclude $c$ from $b$ or not.